# React Ref Object HTMLAElement

Tags: reactjs

I can do any of:

```
React.RefObject<HTMLDivElement>
React.RefObject<HTMLInputElement>
React.RefObject<HTMLSpanElement>
```

But it doesn't work to do:

```
React.RefObject<HTMLAElement>
```

For `<a>` tags.

It seems they choose not to do a logical naming convention?

Cannot find any documentation which lists the conversion between 'HTML tag' and 'how react arbitrarily decided to call it'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `a` in the `<a></a>` element is stand for `Anchor`. So if you want to use the anchor element type you can simply use the `HTMLAnchorElement`.

According to the [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLAnchorElement) documentation:

> The HTMLAnchorElement interface represents hyperlink elements and provides special properties and methods (beyond those of the regular HTMLElement object interface that they inherit from) for manipulating the layout and presentation of such elements. This interface corresponds to  element

You can also see the list of `HTML` types on the [MDN web API's page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API), in `H` column.

Answer (score 3):

You can easily get the type of a element as follows (type in your browser console, not in a script):

```js
const t = document.createElement('a');
console.log(t.__proto__);
```

As you can see a `<a>` element will be a `HTMLAnchorElement`. This is built into HTML and is not react/typescript specific. Replace 'a' with any other element to get it's type.